# What is the right way to import modules inside my class

Tags: python

I am new to python and I'm trying to add math module inside my class but I don't know what is the right way adding it

```
import math
class myClass():
    #some code
```

or

```
class myClass():
    import math
    #some code
```

What is the right way the first or the second one?

Comment: The first import is for the type of import that gets used all around your program. The second one is the type for specific use. Usually sparse.

Answer (score 3):

Anything declared inside a class definition becomes a class variable, a module included, so by importing `math` within a class definition, it becomes a class variable that is accessible only via the class object or the instance object, so:

```
class myClass:
    import math

    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def sqrt(self):
        return math.sqrt(self.value)

print(myClass(4).sqrt())
```

would result in:

```
NameError: name 'math' is not defined
```

but changing the `sqrt` method to:

```
def sqrt(self):
    return self.math.sqrt(self.value)
```

would properly output:

```
2.0
```

That said, there is usually no good reasons to import modules as class variables. In the vast majority of cases modules are imported outside the class, as global variables.

Comment: i understand it now..but can you explain this...someone said  that i  just import it on the module level..i dont understand what he meant

Comment: Importing it on the module level actually means the same as importing it as a global variable. In Python a global variable (one that is declared outside a function and a class) simply becomes an attribute of the current module.